# JPA Eclipse link mapping issue -duplicate entries in child table

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

While updating parent class  (eg : only setting one column and trying to update that one so its inserting  thousands of duplicate child rows).

Is there any bug in eclipse link. We are using java 8 and eclipse link 2.7.4

Please find the following code snippet.
Parent class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH},orphanRemoval=false,
 fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CascadeOnDelete
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Child> child;


child class
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
     @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="ID1", referencedColumnName="ID1"),
            @JoinColumn(name="ID2", referencedColumnName="ID2")
        })
    @CacheIndex
    private Parent parent;  


    EntityManager em = EMFUtil.getEMFactory().createEntityManager();
    parent.setAmount(1000);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(parent);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Thanks in advance
Arnav

Comment: add service code where you are  updating/inserting Parent class

Comment: It was working fine with Vaadin JPA Container, recently changed to Spring data repository. After that duplicate rows are inserting in to child row.

Comment: There are many bugs, but that is true of any product and shouldn't be the question: You are not likely hitting a bug in the provider, but in your code and some of its assumptions. Merge takes in an Entity object and will find the existing Entity it represents and merge in the changes, OR insert a new Entity graph if it wasn't found. Your code is causing the later. To find out why, you'd need to look at what that 'parent' object is, how it was read (or created) and what ID values it and the graph has.

Comment: Thank you, it saved my day. I was fetching entity objects directly from the spring data query and setting values in to it, now instead of fetching directly entity objects changed to primary key and retrieving entity object from that. It working fine now.